# Dereferencing string iterator yields int

Tags: c++, string, iterator, dereference

I get this error

```
comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'const char *')
```

For the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::string s("test string");
    for(auto i = s.begin(); i != s.end(); ++i)
    {
        cout << ((*i) != "s") << endl;
    }
}
```

Why does dereferencing the string iterator yield an `int` and not `std::string`?

Comment: You should write `cout << ((*i) != 's') << endl;` (note the single quotes).

Comment: You are comparing a character (`*i`) with a pointer to a string (`"s"`). That can't work.

Comment: if you use `auto` already, why not use range-for as in `for (auto const& c : s) { cout << (c != 's') << '\n'; }`? (note that you rarely want to use `endl` and most often `\n`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, it does not yield an `int`, it yields a `char` (because a string iterator iterates over the characters in the string). Since the other operand of `!=` is not a `char` (it's a `const char[2]`), standard promotions and conversions are applied to the arguments:

- `char` is promoted to `int` via integral promotion
- `const char[2]` is converted to `const char*` via array-to-pointer conversion,

This is how you arrive at the `int` and `const char*` operands the compiler is complaining about.

You should compare the dereferenced iterator to a *character,* not to a *string:*

```
cout << ((*i) != 's') << endl;
```

`""` encloses a string literal (type `const char[N]`), `''` encloses a character literal (type `char`).